# Adding the data table and data set into one datatable

Tags: javascript, java, c#, .net, c#-3.0

I have a DataTable and some data. Another is a DataSet. Both have the data. Is it possible to combine these two?

Code:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Add(Some columns);

Dataset ds=new Dataset();
ds.Add(some columns);
```

dt=ds+dt???

Comment: You can add datatables to the dataset. You can do like `ds.Tables.Add(dt);`

Answer (score 0):

```
DataColum dc = new DataColumn("name");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(column);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```